# How to stop the frame moving when I call the function again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

For my homework I have to draw a rectangle frame and the turtle should be a dot and moving to a random destination.

When I press the space bar(which starts and stops the simulation), the frame starts changing position bouncing with the dot. The dot is also not moving but only bounce in the center.

'''

```
import turtle
import random

#used to infect 
class Virus:
    def __init__(self, colour, duration):
        self.colour = colour
        self.duration = duration

## This class represents a person
class Person:
    def __init__(self, world_size):
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.radius = 7
        self.location = turtle.position()
        self.destination = self._get_random_location()

    #random locations are used to assign a destination for the person
    #the possible locations should not be closer than 1 radius to the edge of the world 
    def _get_random_location(self):
        x = random.randint(-349, 349)
        y = random.randint(-249, 249)
        return (x, y)


    #draw a person using a dot.  Use colour if implementing Viruses 
    def draw(self):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.home()
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.dot(self.radius*2)


    #returns true if within 1 radius
    def reached_destination(self):
        self.location = turtle.position()
        distX = abs(abs(self.destination[0])-abs(self.location[0]))
        distY = abs(abs(self.destination[1])- abs(self.location[1]))
        if distX and distY < self.radius:
            return True
        else:
            pass



    #Updates the person each hour.
    #- moves each person by calling the move method
    #- if the destination is reached then set a new destination
    #- progress any illness
    def update(self):
        self.move()
        if self.reached_destination():
            self._get_random_location()

        else:
            self.move()

    #moves person towards the destination
    def move(self):
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
        turtle.forward(self.radius/2)


class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, n):
        self.size = (width, height)
        self.hours = 0
        self.people = []
        self.add_person()


    #add a person to the list
    def add_person(self):
        person = Person(1)
        self.people.append(person)

    #simulate one hour in the world.
    #- increase hours passed.
    #- update all people
    #- update all infection transmissions
    def simulate(self):
        self.hours += 1
        for item in self.people:
            item.update()

    #Draw the world.  Perform the following tasks:
    #   - clear the current screen
    #   - draw all the people
    #   - draw the box that frames the world
    #   - write the number of hours and number of people infected at the top of the frame
    def draw(self):
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.forward(250)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(350)
        turtle.left(180)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(700)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(500)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(700)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(500)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.forward(500)
        turtle.write(f'Hours: {self.hours}', False, 'left')
        turtle.update()
        for item in self.people:
            item.draw()



#---------------------------------------------------------
#Should not need to alter any of the code below this line
#---------------------------------------------------------
class GraphicalWorld:
    """ Handles the user interface for the simulation

    space - starts and stops the simulation
    'z' - resets the application to the initial state
    'x' - infects a random person
    'c' - cures all the people
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.WIDTH = 800
        self.HEIGHT = 600
        self.TITLE = 'COMPSCI 130 Project One'
        self.MARGIN = 50 #gap around each side
        self.PEOPLE = 200 #number of people in the simulation
        self.framework = AnimationFramework(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT, self.TITLE)

        self.framework.add_key_action(self.setup, 'z') 
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.infect, 'x')
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.cure, 'c')
        self.framework.add_key_action(self.toggle_simulation, ' ') 
        self.framework.add_tick_action(self.next_turn)

        self.world = None

    def setup(self):
        """ Reset the simulation to the initial state """
        print('resetting the world')        
        self.framework.stop_simulation()
        self.world = World(self.WIDTH - self.MARGIN * 2, self.HEIGHT - self.MARGIN * 2, self.PEOPLE)
        self.world.draw()

    def infect(self):
        """ Infect a person, and update the drawing """
        print('infecting a person')
        self.world.infect_person()
        self.world.draw()

    def cure(self):
        """ Remove infections from all the people """
        print('cured all people')
        self.world.cure_all()
        self.world.draw()

    def toggle_simulation(self):
        """ Starts and stops the simulation """
        if self.framework.simulation_is_running():
            self.framework.stop_simulation()
        else:
            self.framework.start_simulation()           

    def next_turn(self):
        """ Perform the tasks needed for the next animation cycle """
        self.world.simulate()
        self.world.draw()

## This is the animation framework
## Do not edit this framework
class AnimationFramework:
    """This framework is used to provide support for animation of
       interactive applications using the turtle library.  There is
       no need to edit any of the code in this framework.
    """
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.title = title
        self.simulation_running = False
        self.tick = None #function to call for each animation cycle
        self.delay = 1 #smallest delay is 1 millisecond      
        turtle.title(title) #title for the window
        turtle.setup(width, height) #set window display
        turtle.hideturtle() #prevent turtle appearance
        turtle.tracer(0, 0) #prevent turtle animation
        turtle.listen() #set window focus to the turtle window
        turtle.mode('logo') #set 0 direction as straight up
        turtle.penup() #don't draw anything
        turtle.setundobuffer(None)
        self.__animation_loop()

    def start_simulation(self):
        self.simulation_running = True

    def stop_simulation(self):
        self.simulation_running = False

    def simulation_is_running(self):
        return self.simulation_running

    def add_key_action(self, func, key):
        turtle.onkeypress(func, key)

    def add_tick_action(self, func):
        self.tick = func

    def __animation_loop(self):
        try:
            if self.simulation_running:
                self.tick()
            turtle.ontimer(self.__animation_loop, self.delay)
        except turtle.Terminator:
            pass


gw = GraphicalWorld()
gw.setup()
turtle.mainloop()
```

'''

The turtle dot should be bouncing slowly to the random location and the frame should stay still when I press the space bar. And I know the code is long sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the frame starts changing position bouncing with the dot. The dot is
>   also not moving but only bounce in the center.

I've reworked your `Person` and `World` classes below to address these two issues.  This simulation model you're given uses a single turtle which means we have to play by certain rules:

- Each `Person` must keep track of their own position and heading
- Only the `draw()` method should have the pen down, all other `Person` methods should have the pen up if using the turtle to do calculations
- Whenever a `Person` uses the turtle, you can't assume anything about it as another `Person` was just using the turtle so you must set your heading, position and pen state

The changed portion of your posted code:

```
FONT = ('Arial', 16, 'normal')

# This class represents a person
class Person():
    def __init__(self, world_size):
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.radius = 7
        self.location = turtle.position()
        self.destination = self._get_random_location()

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(self.location)
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
        self.heading = turtle.heading()

    # random locations are used to assign a destination for the person
    # the possible locations should not be closer than 1 radius to the edge of the world
    def _get_random_location(self):
        x = random.randint(self.radius - 349, 349 - self.radius)
        y = random.randint(self.radius - 249, 249 - self.radius)
        return (x, y)

    # draw a person using a dot.  Use colour if implementing Viruses
    def draw(self):
        x, y = self.location

        # use .circle() not .dot() as the latter causes an extra update (flicker)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(x, y - self.radius)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.circle(self.radius)
        turtle.end_fill()

    # returns true if within 1 radius
    def reached_destination(self):
        distX = abs(self.destination[0] - self.location[0])
        distY = abs(self.destination[1] - self.location[1])
        return distX < self.radius and distY < self.radius

    # Updates the person each hour.
    # - moves each person by calling the move method
    # - if the destination is reached then set a new destination
    # - progress any illness
    def update(self):
        self.move()

        if self.reached_destination():
            self.destination = self._get_random_location()
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setposition(self.location)
            turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
            self.heading = turtle.heading()

    # moves person towards the destination
    def move(self):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setheading(self.heading)
        turtle.setposition(self.location)
        turtle.forward(self.radius / 2)
        self.location = turtle.position()

class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, n):
        self.size = (width, height)
        self.hours = 0
        self.people = []
        for _ in range(n):
            self.add_person()

    # add a person to the list
    def add_person(self):
        person = Person(1)
        self.people.append(person)

    # simulate one hour in the world.
    # - increase hours passed.
    # - update all people
    # - update all infection transmissions
    def simulate(self):
        self.hours += 1

        for item in self.people:
            item.update()

    # Draw the world.  Perform the following tasks:
    # - clear the current screen
    # - draw all the people
    # - draw the box that frames the world
    # - write the number of hours and number of people infected at the top of the frame
    def draw(self):
        turtle.clear()  # also undoes hideturtle(), etc.
        turtle.hideturtle()
        turtle.setheading(0)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(-350, -250)

        turtle.pendown()

        for _ in range(2):
            turtle.forward(500)
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(700)
            turtle.right(90)

        for item in self.people:
            item.draw()

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.setposition(-350, -250)

        # leave this to the end as .write() forces an extra update (flicker)
        turtle.write(f'Hours: {self.hours}', move=False, align='left', font=FONT)

        turtle.update()
```

I've also included some tweaks to reduce flicker.  I'm sure there's lots more work to be done.

If we wanted to run this simulation faster, we'd make each `Person` a separate turtle (e.g. via inheritance) and use the reshaped turtle itself as it's presence on the screen and not *draw* the `Person`.  And we'd throw separate turtles at the outline frame and the text to simplify updates.

[image]